# TinyMCE Inline Editor Not Appearing in React Component

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Body:
I am facing an issue where the TinyMCE Inline Editor is not appearing as expected in my React application. I am using JSX and have integrated TinyMCE with React.

Problem:
When I run my application, all I see is a textbox without the TinyMCE editor interface. I am not using a textarea element; I am directly using the Editor component from @tinymce/tinymce-react.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, Grid, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { createInstructions } from "../../../reducers/assessment";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

// TinyMCE so the global var exists
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
// DOM model
// Theme
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';
// Toolbar icons
import 'tinymce/icons/default';
// Editor styles
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css';

// importing the plugin js.
// if you use a plugin that is not listed here the editor will fail to load
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist';
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor';
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink';
import 'tinymce/plugins/autoresize';
import 'tinymce/plugins/autosave';
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap';
import 'tinymce/plugins/code';
import 'tinymce/plugins/codesample';
import 'tinymce/plugins/directionality';
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons';
import 'tinymce/plugins/fullscreen';
import 'tinymce/plugins/help';
import 'tinymce/plugins/image';
import 'tinymce/plugins/importcss';
import 'tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/plugins/media';
import 'tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking';
import 'tinymce/plugins/pagebreak';
import 'tinymce/plugins/preview';
import 'tinymce/plugins/quickbars';
import 'tinymce/plugins/save';
import 'tinymce/plugins/searchreplace';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/template';
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualblocks';
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualchars';
import 'tinymce/plugins/wordcount';

// importing plugin resources
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis';


const CreateInstructions = ({ scroll, onEnter, isOpen, onLeave, isExpanded, createInstruction }) => {

    const instructions = useSelector((state) => state.assessment.instructions);
    const [instruction, setInstruction] = React.useState(instructions);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("instruction ", instruction);
    }, []);


    const handleEditInstruction = () => {
        setInstruction(instructions);
    };

    const handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
        console.log("instruction ", instruction);

        console.log("Handle Editor change");
        setInstruction(content);
    };

    const handleAddInstruction = () => {
        console.log("handleAddInstruction");
        dispatch(createInstructions(instruction))
        setInstruction('');
    }

    const style = {
        width: isOpen ? "45%" : "0px",
        height: "67vh",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        transition: "width 0.3s ease-in-out",
        overflowY: scroll ? "auto" : "hidden",
        padding: isOpen ? "20px" : "0px",
    };

    return (
        <div style={style} onMouseEnter={onEnter} onMouseLeave={onLeave}>
            <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Box
                    sx={{ cursor: 'pointer', color: 'grey', '&:hover': { color: 'black' } }}
                >
                    <Button variant="text" color="primary" onClick={handleAddInstruction}>
                        {instructions ? 'Save Instruction' : 'Save Instruction'}
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Grid>
                <Editor
                style={{ flex: 1, height: '800px', width: '300px' }}
                init={{
                    placeholder: "Enter your subquestion here...",
                    height: '800px',
                    menubar: true,
                    block_unsupported_drop: false,
                    file_picker_types: 'image',
                    automatic_uploads: true,
                    file_picker_callback: (callback, value, meta) => {
                        const input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                        input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                            const file = event.target.files[0];
                            const reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                                const id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                                const blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                                const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                                const blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                                blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                                /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                                callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                            });
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        })
                        input.click();
                    },
                    plugins: [
                        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap anchor',
                        'searchreplace visualblocks fullscreen',
                        'insertdatetime media table help wordcount',
                    ],
                    toolbar: 'undo redo | fontsize |' +
                        'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent' +
                        'removeformat| image table | help',
                    htmlAllowedTags: ['.*'],
                    htmlAllowedAttrs: ['.*'],
                    extended_valid_elements: '*[.*]',
                    font_size_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt',
                    external_plugins: {
                        'tiny_mce_wiris': '/node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-tinymce6/plugin.min.js'
                    },
                    inline: true
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default CreateInstructions;
```

Additional Context:
I have imported all the necessary plugins and themes for TinyMCE.
I have set the inline option to true in the init object.
I tried modularizing the TinyMCE editor into its own component, but the editor still doesn't appear.

Side Problem:
It seems like I have to import all plugins directly in the component for it to work. When I tried to put the TinyMCE editor in its own component and import it, the editor did not appear.

I would appreciate any help or insights into solving this issue. Thank you in advance!

What I've Tried:
Checked the console and network tab for errors (none found).
Ensured that all plugins are imported.

I was expecting to click on the text box and see the inline editor pop up.